# Android null object reference when insert data into sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite, nullpointerexception, android-sqlite

When I insert data into sqlite database in the logcat it prompt up the null object reference. But with the same code i using in another program it can work. Can i have some suggestion to solve this question.

this is my DBControl

```
public void addProduct(Product product) {
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();

    cv.put(Code,product.getProductCode());
    cv.put(Description,product.getProductName());
    cv.put(MenuDepartment,product.getMenuDepartment());
    cv.put(CondimentGroup,product.getCondimentGroup1());
    cv.put(ModifierGroup,product.getModifierGroup1());
    //inserting row
    db.insert(mproduct, null, cv);
    //close the database to avoid any leak
    db.close();
}
```

this is how i insert data when button click.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_printer_test_demo);
    innitView();

}
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_printer_test_demo);
    innitView();

}


private void innitView() {


    new BitmapUtils(this);
    b_table = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b_table);
    b_additem = (Button)findViewById(R.id.additem);
    findViewById(R.id.additem).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.b_exit).setOnClickListener(this);
    b_additem.setOnClickListener(this);
    b_table.setOnClickListener(this);

    info = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.info);

    callback = new ICallback.Stub() {

        @Override
        public void onRunResult(final boolean success) throws RemoteException {
        }

        @Override
        public void onReturnString(final String value) throws RemoteException {
            Log.i(TAG,"printlength:" + value + "\n");
        }

        @Override
        public void onRaiseException(int code, final String msg) throws RemoteException {
            Log.i(TAG,"onRaiseException: " + msg);
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    info.append("onRaiseException = " + msg + "\n");
                }});

        }
    };

    setButtonEnable(false);

    Intent intent=new Intent();
    intent.setPackage("woyou.aidlservice.jiuiv5");
    intent.setAction("woyou.aidlservice.jiuiv5.IWoyouService");
    startService(intent);
    bindService(intent, connService, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
}

private void setButtonEnable(boolean flag){


    b_table.setEnabled(flag);
    b_additem.setEnabled(flag);

}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.b_table:
            //打印表格
            printTable();
            break;
        case R.id.additem:
                additem();
            break;

        }
}

public void additem(){
        try {

                    DBControl db = new DBControl(context);<------the logcat show the error at here
                    db.addProduct(new Product("10001", "Nasi Lemak", "A", "C1", "M1"));
                    db.addProduct(new Product("10002", "STEAM LOTUS LEAF GLUTINOUS RICE", "A", "C1", "M1"));
                    db.addProduct(new Product("10003", "EIGHT TREASURE GLUTINOUS RICE", "B", "C2", "M2"));
                    db.addProduct(new Product("10004", "CHICKEN PORRIDGE & DRIED SCALLOP", "B", "C2", "M2"));
                    db.addProduct(new Product("10005", "FISH PORRIDGE", "C", "C3", "M3"));
                    db.addProduct(new Product("10006", "LAKSA", "C", "C3", "M3"));
            }catch(SQLiteException e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
            }
}
```

logcat

```
  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.test.printertestdemo.DBControl.addProduct(com.test.printertestdemo.Constructor.Product)' on a null object reference
                  at com.test.printertestdemo.PrinterTestDemoAct.additem(PrinterTestDemoAct.java:181)
                  at com.test.printertestdemo.PrinterTestDemoAct.onClick(PrinterTestDemoAct.java:173)
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4848)
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20262)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5637)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:960)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

Comment: Are you sure that this is the code you're actually executing? Log the value of `db` after the`new DBControl` call.

Comment: @CL.yes this code actually work, when i debugging the code i get DBControl is null

Comment: `DBControl db = new DBControl(context);` Quite obviously, you don't have a valid context here.

Comment: @Rotwang but i have tried i declare the DBControl = db at the top, it still get the null value

Comment: replace this "context" with getApplicationContext(). may be resolve your problem  or if you using Activity pass "this"

Comment: You don't have a Context, because you're probably not inside an Activity.

Answer (score 0):

on your on create define

```
Context context = getContext();
```

on calling method item pass context

```
addItem(context);
```

in your method add parameter Context context;
then it will work.

If that not works then use

```
Activity context = getActivity();
```

in first step.
Hope It helps.